# How to hand R objects to C++ using Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

How to hand R objects to C++ using Rcpp?

Hey, I am new to Rcpp and have the following problem (which is probably pretty straightforward but I could not figure it out). I first create a list, vectors and a data frame in R. I want to pass these R objects to C++ to modify the list and then return the modified list again back to R for further analysis.

I made up an example of a cpp file in Rstudio:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

/*** R
mylist <- list(mat1 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat2 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat3 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat4 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))))
myvector1 <- c(seq(8,10,1))
myvector2 <- c(seq(101,103,1))

mydataframe <- data.frame(Col1 = c('id3','id4','id5'), Col2 = seq(21,23,1), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black')))
*/


// [[Rcpp::export]]

// Some code modifying mylist with myvector1, myvector2 and mydataframe and returning the modified list again to R
// Let's say Col2 of mat1 of mylist shall be multiplied with myvector1 and Col 2 of mat2 with myvector2. 
// Col2 of mat4 shall be divided by Col2 of mydataframe
// And then the modified mylist should be returned
}

/*** R
# Some analysis with the new modified list generated in the C++ code
summary(mylist$mat2$Col2)
*/
```

How can I make an operation like this generally work (in reality my list is much larger)? Or is it better using an Rscript with the cxxfunction function? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems your question is how to *practically* combine R and C++ using Rcpp. I see several approaches. Which one to choose depends on the amount of code, how often you do similar analysis, how likely you will have to come back to this particular analysis in the future, etc. It is a good idea to try them out yourself so that you can form your own heuristics when to choose which.

## Single file

### C++ plus R

If there is more C++ than R it is useful to have a single `cpp` with a special R comment. General structure:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo(Rcpp::List l, Rcpp::NumericVector v1, Rcpp::NumericVector v2, Rcpp::DataFrame df) {
    Rcpp::List mat2 = l["mat2"];
    Rcpp::NumericVector Col2 = mat2["Col2"];
    Col2(0) = 10;
}

/*** R
mylist <- list(mat1 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat2 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat3 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))),
               mat4 = data.frame(Col1 = c('id1','id2','id3'), Col2 = c(5,6,7), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black'))))
myvector1 <- c(seq(8,10,1))
myvector2 <- c(seq(101,103,1))

mydataframe <- data.frame(Col1 = c('id3','id4','id5'), Col2 = seq(21,23,1), Col3 = as.factor(c('blue','green','black')))

foo(mylist, myvector1, myvector2, mydataframe)

summary(mylist$mat2$Col2)
*/
```

This is similar to what you have but with only a single R comment. You need to call `Rcpp::sourceCpp("<file>")` to have this compiled and the code in the R comment executed. In RStudio you can use "Source" for this.

Note that in the above example the list is changed by reference, which can be dangerous, since R follows a copy on write policy. For large lists this is of course expensive, which is probably why you are looking for C++ solutions.

### R plus C++

If there is only very little C++ code you can use `Rcpp:cppFunction("<C++ code>")`. I would not use `inline::cxxfunction` anymore. I rarely use this approach since there is no editor support for the C++ code.

### R Markdown

R Markdown allows you to combine R and C++ on equal footing using `r` and `rcpp` chunks. This is very useful if you want to add some prose to the analysis. In RStudio you get editor support for both types of chunks. However, sometimes the error messages from the C++ compiler get mangled up making them even harder to interpret.

## Multiple files

### Project

If the amount of code increases or data files enter you might consider some sort of project structure, e.g. directories `data`, `R`, and `src` for data files, R scripts with function definitions and C++ files. The driver file (R or Rmd) would then load the data, `source` the R scripts and `sourceCpp` the C++ files before  doing the actual analysis.

### R package

Once you use a project structure, you can also go for a package. For little extra work you get several advantages:

- C++ code needs to be compiled only once
- R functions are byte compiled right away
- C++ functions can easily be used with parallel processing
- clear strucutre to integrate documentation and tests
- ...

Note that you can start with an empty package and a single Rmd file. In the beginning, you only use the Rmd file. Every now and then you can refactor the code to move part of it as R or C++ functions into the package.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer - there are a lot of things to think about going forward for me from what you mentioned. Once question which prevails is how do it get my R objects (lists, data frames etc.) into my C++ part of the code? Or is it "only" possible to write a C++ function which is then called within the R environment with the R objects? Or is it possible to have a direct "interface" to hand the R objects to the C++ environment and then work with them in C++ and vice versa?

Comment: @sh_student I have made the first example more concrete. HTH.